# Are electric gadgets running/working or just switched/left on?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In normal usage(daily more-like), I use sentences/phrases such as:

> 1. Water pumps are **running**.
> 2. **Switch on** the fan.
> 3. My system has been **working** for 20 days now.

Most of us use similar phrases too(even if our mother-tongue is not English, the closest match would still be among one of the three listed above).

I know that none of them are wrong. But when generally talking about electric/electronic devices or gadgets, should the verbs like *running* be used?

What other words are there that can be used instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Running* implies a kind of specific activity. Pumps can be running when they're pumping, or your computer can be running when it's generating CPU cycles of something.

When something is *on*, it simply means its essential parts are receiving power (probably electric). When a pump isn't running, it's probably not using power, so there is no difference in meaning. *On* implies that there is a kind of binary switch somewhere: it's either on or off.

*Work* can mean two things:

1. When something *works*, it is not defective.
2. When it is *working*, it is occupied working on a task. You computer has been working on a certain task for 20 days, like cracking a huge database of encrypted passwords. If it hasn't been working on specific tasks all the time, then you wouldn't say it has been *working* for 20 days, but rather *running*. Or it has been *on* for 20 days.

Comment: +1 particularly for the two relevant senses of "work". But you might consider expanding the distinction between *running* and *on* to clarify why we never say things like *"I think I left the kitchen light running"*. I'm not exactly sure what it is about "running", since you can definitely use it for computers - and (at a pinch, maybe) televisions. So it's not quite just a matter of saying *running = operating (of some device with moving parts)*.

Answer (score 2):

This varies a lot by culture.  I've heard many of my foreign students that learned English in other places refer to a light being "closed" instead of "on".  In America we might refer to a "closed" circuit in technical circles, but not in everyday English.

"On" means that there is some sort of power flowing.
"Running" means that it is doing something.
"Working" means that it is doing something productive OR that there are no problems with it's function.

Although these are subtleties, and usually you can use any of the three.

The subtleties and multiple meanings make this confusing:

"My engine is running, but I can't make the car move."  In this case your engine may not be working to move the car, but it is running (burning gas and making noise).
"I can't open your e-mail right now, my computer is working on something."  In this case you are indicating that your computer is very busy.
"My computer is working fine." Indicates there is no problem with the function of your computer, but it might not be "on" at this very moment.

If something is "not working" or "not running" it may indicate a larger problem then just needing to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

As for *running* vs *left on*, an appliance or piece of equipment can be *left on* but not *running* – if it's not been powered off, but it's not doing anything, either.

For example, consider my DVR: I can *leave it on* all day, but it would only be *running* if it was recording, or I was watching a movie.

The terminology can vary slightly depending on how the device is designed. If you can power a device on or off without it doing anything else, then it can be *left on* even when it's not *running*; examples would include a cell phone or a computer. However, some devices can't powered on unless they are actually doing something, like a toaster. You can't simply *leave a toaster on*.

Fans can be turned on, but, once they are on, they are running. You can leave a fan running, and you can leave a fan turned off. If you leave a fan turned on, though, the implication is that the fan is running – but that wouldn't hold true for a monitor.

And some devices don't really run at all. For example, I can't imagine myself saying, "the radio is running." It's hard to state a general rule that will work in all circumstances, but I would say that if the device has a motor, then it runs, and if it doesn't have a motor, it doesn't run. That's why my DVD player and my refrigerator both *run*, but my television and my oven are simply *on*.